# Is this UTF-8 implementation implementation-defined or well-defined?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8

I just browsed around looking for some implementation of UTF-8 code points (and no, not to plagiarize) and stumbled across [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/jGr2bZXWntc):

> ```
> typedef unsigned char char8_t;
> typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> u8string;
> ```

Is this code ignoring the fact that `CHAR_BIT` is only required to be at least `8`, but may be greater? Or does this not matter in this context and the code is fine? If so, then why is this?

Also, someone (presumably SO member @NicolBolas?) wrote this:

> ```
> const char *str = u8"This is a UTF-8 string.";
> ```
>
> This is pretty much how UTF-8 will be used in C++ for string literals.

I thought that a code unit in UTF-8 is always exactly eight bits!
From the Unicode Standard 8.0.0, Chapter 2.5:

> In the Unicode character encoding model, precisely defined encoding
>   forms specify how each integer (code point) for a Unicode character is
>   to be expressed as a sequence of one or more code units. The Unicode
>   Standard provides three distinct encoding forms for Unicode
>   characters, using **8-bit**, 16- bit, and 32-bit units. These are
>   named **UTF-8**, UTF-16, and UTF-32, respectively.

<sub>(Newlines removed, hyphen on line-break removed, emphasis added.)</sub>

So why does he claim `const char*` is used instead of `const uint8_t*` (or the suggested, hypothetical `const char8_t*`)?

Comment: @skypjack I rolled back to my version. The first code is a quotation, even though there's no real text.

Comment: So good a question, but there were few visual flaws in the quotes, so I removed them and nothing more. Am I wrong and it was my mobile app that didn't format correctly the question?

Comment: @skypjack Well... it didn't look better, let's put it diplomatically. :-)

Comment: @skypjack: Your edit (a) removed the quotation tag of the first code block, (b) removed the code tag of the second quotation, and (c) lost the new text that had been added in the prior revision. There was nothing useful in that edit, mobile or otherwise!

Comment: Damn it, I'm so sorry. I just found that: (a) the mobile app does a mess in showing code within a quote (and I've never noticed it before) and (b) it doesn't take care at all if I submit an edit that is in conflict with a new version of the question/answer. Well, let me write down not to edit a question/answer anymore unless I'm doing it from the web. I apologize for the inconvenient, you did right to rollback it, absolutely!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why does he claim `const char*` is used instead of `const uint8_t*` (or the suggested, hypothetical `const char8_t*`)?

Because that's what the standard says. a `u8` literal string will resolve to an array of type `const char[N]`. That's how UTF-8 literals in C++ are defined to work.

If `char` on a system has more than 8 bits... so be it. Each `char` in the string will still hold a value between 0 and 255, which is the range of valid UTF-8 code units. Even though `char` could hold large values on such system.

If `char` cannot hold 8 bits... then the implementation is invalid. By recent wording of the standard, `char` is required to hold enough bits to store every valid UTF-8 code unit. And technically, 255 is not a valid UTF-8 code unit.

And the fact of the matter is this: there's already a *huge* amount of code that accepts UTF-8 via `char*`. They aren't going to rewrite POSIX, filesystem APIs, and whatever else to adopt a different type.

That being said, manipulating a sequence of UTF-8 code units via `const char*` is... dubious. This is because they could be signed. However, the recent standard wording requires that a conversion between `unsigned char` and `char` work within the range of valid UTF-8 code units. That is, you can cast a `const char*` to a `const unsigned char*`, do your bit manipulation on that, and then cast it back, and you're guaranteed to work.

> And what's the point of that super-complex "recent wording of the standard"?

The point of that is to allow UTF-8 strings to actually *work*. Because the standards committee, in their "infinite wisdom", decided not to include a special `char8_t` UTF-8 code unit type, they had to add wording to make `char` serve in that role. And that requires that the conversion to/from `unsigned char` and `char` to not be able to mangle a UTF-8 code unit.

There was even a [discussion topic on the C++ standard discussion forums](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/6eYafw4jUZI/discussion), where the [wording was discussed (search for 1759)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3914.html). The C++14 wording says:

> For each value `i` of type `unsigned char` in the range 0 to 255 inclusive, there exists a value `j` of type `char` such that the result of an integral conversion (4.7) from `i` to `char` is `j`, and the result of an integral conversion from `j` to `unsigned char` is `i`.

This means in particular that `char` could only be signed by default if the signed representation satisfies the above. A one's complement signed `char` would not be sufficient, since negative zero has a special representation (0x80), which when converted to unsigned becomes regular 0.

Should they have just defined a specific `char8_t` that is required to be unsigned and has at least 8 bits? Probably. But it's done and it ain't changing.

Comment: " And technically, 255 is not a valid UTF-8 code unit." What. `255` fits into 8 bits, so why not into a UTF-8 code unit? And what's the point of that super-complex "recent wording of the standard"? And what do you mean with bit manipulation? I thought a `const char*` disallows modification when dereferenced.

Comment: And why `char` and not `unsigned char`? What if `char` is signed? Wouldn't that be implementation-defined behavior?

Comment: `255 fits into 8 bits, so why not into a UTF-8 code unit?` If you look at details of UTF-8 encoding, every octet that can be part of a valid UTF-8 sequence would have at least one 0 bit in it. The largest possible octet is, I think, `11110111b == 247`

Comment: @cad: "what do you mean with bit manipulation?" A `char` is ultimately just a number, an integer. And you can do bit manipulation on an integer. UTF-8 processing requires that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, OK, but technically it does fit into an 8-bit code unit. `255` not fitting into a byte would seem... peculiar.

Comment: @NicolBolas did not say "255 would not fit into [whatever]" - you did (and are now arguing against a strawman of your own creation). He or she said, and I quote, "255 is not a valid UTF-8 code unit" - by which I presume it was meant that "an octet with the value 255 cannot appear in a valid UTF-8 sequence", a true statement.

Answer (score 3):

`uint8_t` only exists on systems that have memory that's accessible as **exactly** 8 bits. UTF-8 doesn't have any such requirement. It uses values that fit into 8 bits, but does not impose any requirements on how those values are actually stored. Each 8-bit value could be stored as 16 bits or 32 bits or whatever makes sense for the system that it's running on; the only requirement is that the value must be correct.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this. Let's take a UTF-8 string. Every code unit is eight bits. Now store it in RAM, every byte being **nine** bits. Won't these different byte units somehow overlap and cause a humongous catastrophe?

Comment: @cad: of course not, if you store this string in 9-bit byte memory, each character is still stored in a separate byte.

Comment: @cad - no, that's not a problem. If memory is organized as 9-bit chunks, the compiler stores, say, 3 8-bit values in 3 9-bit chunks. The 3 values aren't affected by how they're stored.

Comment: @PeteBecker But the standard defines a code unit in UTF-8 to be 8 bits (there is a citation concerning that in my question). If one byte was 700 bits, how would that be implemented? Just as you explained? It just seems so inconvenient to me.

Comment: @cad - the **values** that have to be stored range from 0 to 255; that's what "8-bit values" means. As long as those values are preserved, it doesn't matter how they're stored. On a system that has addressable 8-bit storage it obviously makes sense to store those values in that 8-bit storage. On a system with 9-bit storage you can store the value 0-255 in 9 bits without any problem and your code won't know the difference.

Comment: OK, I got it now. And when this is transferred to other computers, who takes care of it? The Unicode standard? Is it all converted to octets? That would require some heavy shifting , though...

Comment: `Is it all converted to octets? That would require some heavy shifting , though` Well, whoever chose to architect a system with 9-bit bytes should have thought of that. Serves them right, I say.

Comment: @cad: "And when this is transferred to other computers, who takes care of it?" C++ doesn't say *anything* about what happens when something is transferred "to other computers." This is true of *any* C++ data structure; for that, you have to rely on some form of implementation-defined or undefined behavior.

Comment: @cad - **forget about octets**. It's **values** that matter. The **value** 1 can be stored as a 64-bit `int` and still be 1. No shifting, no magic. It just works.

Answer (score 1):

> **[lex.string]/8** Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of `n` const char”, where `n` is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).

So, whatever else is true, a UTF-8 string literal is a sequence of `char`s.

As to `uint8_t`:

> **7.20.1.1**
>
> 2 The typedef name `uintN_t` designates an unsigned integer type with width `N` and no padding bits. Thus, `uint24_t` denotes such an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.
>
> 3 These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

On a hypothetical system with a `char` larger than 8 bits, `uint8_t` would not be defined.

Comment: Alright, this is the standard's version but why is this? Why can a UTF-8 string legitimately be referred to as a `const char*`?

Comment: For lack of better alternative, I would assume. How would you rather define it instead?

Comment: "On a hypothetical system with a char larger than 8 bits, `uint8_t` would not be defined." I asked about if this very fact is true in chat (Lounge<C++>) and they told me that's wrong because some implementation-defined could be used to implement `uint8_t`.

Comment: `char` represents the smallest addressable unit on a given architecture. If it's possible to define `uint8_t`, then it's also possible, and prudent, to define `char` to have 8 bits. "**[basic.types]/2** For any object ... of trivially copyable type `T` ... the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array of `char` or `unsigned char`."

Comment: "**[intro.memory]/1** The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the *byte*. A byte is at least large enough to contain ... the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation-defined."

Answer (score 0):

*code unit in UTF-8 is always exactly eight bits*.  `unsigned char` is specified to have at least 8 bits, so all code units in UTF-8 fit in type `unsigned char`.

The rationale for the `u8"This is a UTF-8 encoded string constant"` is not the fact that it is stored in 8-bit bytes, but that it is encoded as UTF-8, whereas the source file might have a different encoding.  The `u8string` typedef is consistent with that but a tad confusing if bytes have more than 8 bits.

Using `unsigned char` is a good way to remove the uncertainty regarding the signedness of type `char`.

Answer (score 0):

[char8_t](https://wg21.link/p0482) was voted in for C++20 during a San Diego meeting so this code will not compile.

However, you will be able to use `std::u8string` but remember that it only works with code units and not code points or grapheme clusters so the safe way is to treat is as opaque blob and use 3rd party libraries to mutate it. At least for now.